# Translation for 'abticken' needed

Tags: translation, german-to-english, teen-slang

I couldn't find a match for the german "abticken". What is the word in English for that?

Comment: whats the context? You didnt read only this single word? `Die Uhr tickt/läuft ab - Time is running out`

Answer (score 8):

http://www.sprachnudel.de/woerterbuch/abticken

> "Abticken" bedeutet ausrasten, abgehen rsp. einen Wutanfall bekommen.

Ausrasten: to blow one's top, go ballistic

Comment: Ich hätte die Bedeutung zwar erraten, trotzdem habe ich das so noch nicht gehört, klares +1 daher. *wat dat nich all gift* ;) Sehr interessant finde ich auf jener Seite, dass man angeben kann, ob man das Wort verwenden würde. Nur wo sieht man die Ergebnisse?

Comment: "Austicken" is more common.

Answer (score 3):

Mein erster Gedanke beim Lesen der Frage war abticken im Sinn von "Tick, du bist es!". Wenn früher bei uns ein Fangenspiel erklärt wurde, wurde Sätze wie "Du musst so viele wie möglich **abticken**, die nächste Runde sind die dann auf deiner Seite" verwendet.

Ich kenne aber auch Acorns Definition, dass muss man aus dem Kontext erkennen:

1. Abticken - to blow one's top, go ballistic
2. Abticken - to touch someone when playing tag

Answer (score 0):

I think a more colloquial translation would be "to go nuts" or "to go crazy" in that context. If another context was meant, please let me know :)

Comment: That would be "austicken".

Comment: in some dialects you also say abticken